How to identify the ideal probability threshold for XGBoost Classifier predictions?
Is there any basis in determining the probability threshold in xgb.predict_proba while using XGBClassifier, especially if the data are imbalanced. I know when xgb.predict is used, a probability threshold of 0.5 is assigned by default.

From a decision theoretic perspective, the right way to choose the threshold is to consider the cost or benefit of a correct or incorrect classification, and to classify examples to maximize the expected net benefit, with the expectation being taken with respect to the posterior class probability distribution. This approach is spelled out in various textbooks; I think a web search will find some resources.

@RobertDodier I am doing classification for landslides, any value higher than the probability threshold is considered a landslides

Re: threshold -- yes, understood. The question is how to pick the threshold, which I tried to address. Also, bear in mind that you can also present your results in the form of a ranked list, ordered by class probability, starting at the top, and construct an ROC curve from that. The ROC curve is essentially a summary of the results you would get from every possible threshold -- in that sense, you don't have to pick a single value.
